# Load a picture from an Access database to a TImage component

Tags: image, delphi, ms-access, load, delphi-7

I am trying to load a picture from a specific place in my database to an Image, but my code is running into some problems I can't solve.

Basically I want to load an image that is specified by a unique id, in an application that's meant for different users with different accounts. The image should basically load the picture the user has previously saved.

So first I use the following query to determine the picture I need:

```
procedure TForm12.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ADOQuery7 do
  begin
    Close;
    Sql.Clear;
    Sql.Add('SELECT Profile_Picture FROM profile WHERE username='+QuotedStr(edit12.text));
    Open;
  end;
end;
```

Which works fine, and indeed targets the field that has the picture with the specified username. Then I use the following to load the picture into the empty TImage:

```
procedure TForm12.BitBtn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if ADOquery7.Active then
    begin
      TBlobField(ADOQuery7.FieldByName('Profile_Picture')).SaveToStream(AStream);
      AStream.Position := 0;
      Image6.Picture.Graphic.LoadFromStream(AStream);
    end;
  finally
    AStream.Free;
  end;
```

end;

But I always get an access violation error. Anyone has any ideas what the problem is?
The file I load the image from is stored in an OLE Object-column.

Comment: Be aware that your code is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You can find a more funny explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/859646) and a way to overcome with Delphi's ADO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924629/parameters-in-sql-delphi-7).

Answer (score 1):

> Then i use the following to load the picture into the empty TImage:

Then `Image5.Picture` is also empty and the Graphic object isn't assigned yet; you cannot call `LoadFromStream` on it.

You have to know the graphic type, create and load that graphic, and then assign it to the Image component, like [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11775398/757830) for example.