# How to use TQuery with Oracle SQL syntax for variable assignments and Params?

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, zeos

In a regular Query on Oracle SQL we could use:

```
var_user VARCHAR2(256) := 'eduard'
select * from a_table where user_name = var_user
```

If I use this code in Delphi's `TQuery.SQL.Text` I get the error `Incorrect Token Followed By ":".`.

I believe it is happening because Delphi uses `:` symbol in this case to specify a parameter inside `TQuery.SQL.Text` to be replaced by the values set at `TQuery.Params[]`.

What I really want to do is `SomeVarInsideSQL := :MyParam` and I can't because of that error. What should I do? (delphi-xe3-zeoslib)

Comment: I belive you post incomplete code in your question. because one thing is assing a value to a string, other is create a sql command.

Comment: The value will be used in a SQL command, but it is not relevant which command it is, in the question.

Comment: maybe this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924629/parameters-in-sql-delphi-7

Comment: The example on the question link you gave works with Access, which do not have `:` in it's syntax and then it does not interfere with `Params[]`. The problem in Oracle SQL is on the `:=` tokens.

Comment: have you tried to escape : as ::

Comment: Worked! ;-) Just like '' or &&. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `:` to `::`  if you have to bypass specific TQuery Parameter parsing.