# How to create and use TParameters?

Tags: c++builder, ado, vcl, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I am trying to create and use `TParameters` but run into an Access Violation because the `AddParameter()` method returns NULL.

This is where I am so far. This is on RAD Studio 10.1 Berlin.

```cpp
TParameters *FSQLParams = new TParameters(NULL, __classid(TParameter));
TParameter *Param = FSQLParams->AddParameter();

Param->DataType = ftString; // A/V since Param is NULL 
Param->Direction = pdInput;
Param->Name = "InOutStatus";
```

The value of `Param` is NULL.

Comment: You are not supposed to *create* your own `TParameters`, you are supposed to use the `Parameters` property that is already built in to whatever SQL component you are using to query your database (`TADOQuery`, `TADOStoredProc`, etc).

Comment: Ahh...That explains. Thanks.

Comment: So I changed the line to ```TParameters *FSQLParams = (new TADOQuery(NULL))->Parameters;``` and it works.

Comment: `new TADOQuery(NULL)` is a memory leak in your example.   If you are going to create a `TADOQuery` dynamically (which is perfectly fine), you need to assign an `Owner` to it, or else `delete` it when are done using it: `TADOQuery *query = new TADOQuery(NULL); TParameters *FSQLParams = query->Parameters; ... delete query;` Which would be best handled using a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::auto_ptr` prior to C++11).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16924902/62576) for an example of using parameters in queries. It's Delphi, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: @Remy: It's invalid in the regard that you can't use the query to do anything (including executing a SQL statement with parameters), because you don't have a reference to it. But I've deleted that comment anyway, and replaced it with one that directs the poster to an example of parameter use directly (although in  Delphi, not Builder).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yea, thanks. For a background I am doing a dunitx test for sql commands and I am trying to separate sql and their parameters to isolate them doing the test run. The code that I was trying is to setup a mock query object. This code snippet is just portion for the purpose of asking question, but there is a setup and tear down where this will be deleted. auto pointer has issues with dunitx that I get AV. There is a bug submitted to embarcadero on it.